# Grails - MySQL query results in error: Bad format for Time

Tags: mysql, grails, grails-orm

I have this query (which works fine in mySQL cmdline), but when I run it in grails using executeQuery, I get this error: Bad format for Time

Here's my grails query:

```
def aveTimeToClose = OstFacTicket.executeQuery
("SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(AVG(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(t.closed, t.created)))) as cl " +
"from OstFacTicket t WHERE t.created >= :sdate AND t.created <= :edate AND " +
"t.closed IS NOT NULL", [sdate:start, edate: end])
```

The stack trace errors are:

```
 Error 2012-05-17 00:09:44,356 [http-bio-8080-exec-9] 
ERROR util.JDBCExceptionReporter
- Bad format for Time '187:22:05' in column 1
| Error 2012-05-17 00:09:44,365 [http-bio-8080-exec-9] ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver
```

Running on mySQL cmdline works fine:

```
mysql> SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(AVG(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(t.closed, t.created)))) as cl
from ost_fac_ticket t where created > '2011-01-01 08:12:49' AND created < 
'2011-12-31 10:12:49';
+-----------+
| cl        |
+-----------+
| 187:22:05 |
+-----------+
```

Thanks, I appreciate any help.

Comment: I'd guess that something in JDBC is trying to interpret `187:22:05` as a time-of-day and getting upset because Earth days don't have 187 hours. Perhaps you should do the `sec_to_time` formatting outside the database. That exhausts my Groovy and Grails knowledge and most of my JDBC so I don't feel justified in offering an answer.

Comment: An easy way to see if I'm right is to tweak the query to return, say,  `11:22:05` and see what happens.

Comment: Yes, that was what's causing the problem. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up following [mu is too short](https://stackoverflow.com/users/479863/mu-is-too-short)'s suggestion by just getting the query result in seconds and converting the number of seconds into the format I wanted using groovy.

Basically -

```
def aveTimeToClose = OstFacTicket.executeQuery("SELECT AVG(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(t.closed, t.created))) as cl "+
        "from OstFacTicket t WHERE t.created >= :sdate AND t.created <= :edate AND t.closed IS NOT NULL", [sdate:start, edate: end])
```

The result aveTimeToClose is in seconds, which can easily be converted into datetime format.

Comment: You can accept your own answers and it seem justified here. I don't mind that you based it on my suggestion either, as I said, I don't know enough Grails, Groovy, or JDBC to provide my own answer.